# Why does my PHP code not repeat HTML elements?

Tags: php, html

In this block of code, you will see that I have used HTML to create an item template. Then I have used PHP to create a while loop to repeat the template for every record in my database. (I use phpmyadmin to control my SQL database)

However, the issue is that the template doesn't repeat for every record in the database although it does show for the first record in the database but not the rest. Now I wonder what I should do? The code without the CSS is down below, Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9114d9acc8.js" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/navbar/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include "includes/navbar/navbar.php"; ?>
    <?php
    require 'includes/dbh.php';
    $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM produce');
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    ?>
    <div class="itemTemplate">
        <a id="title" href="register.php"><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></a>
        <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $row['img'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['Name'] ?>"></a>
        <span>Price: £<?php echo $row['Price'] ?></span>
        <div class="flex-b">
            <label for="">Quantity:</label>
            <select name="" id="">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
            <a href="signIn.php"><i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i></a>
        </div>
    
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might just be a display thing: you're closing your outer div outside of (after) the `while` loop, whereas it's opened inside it.

Comment: `id`s also should be unique.

Comment: As well as `name`s.

Comment: Take a look into the browsers source code. Maybe they are present but because of mailformated html the browser will dont display it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'd do it. Some personal preference but I find it much better echoing statments as the HTML is neater and more manageable.

```
 <?php
 $select = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from produce");
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {

 // Assign variables to table indexes
 $img = $row['img'];
 $name = $row['name'];
 $price = $row['price'];

 // Echo statement in while loop
 echo "
 <div class='itemTemplate'>
 <a id='title' href='register.php'>$name</a>
 <a href=''><img src='$img' alt='$name'></a>
 <span>Price: £$price</span>
 <div class='flex-b'>
 <label for=''>Quantity:</label>
 <select name='' id=''>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
 <option>6</option>
 <option>7</option>
 <option>8</option>
 </select>
 <a href='signIn.php'><i class='fas fa-shopping-basket'></i></a>
 </div>
 ";

 // End while loop after looped HTML content.
 }
 ?>
```